# How can I control the length of hair particles

Tags: particles

[image]

I made this object with hair particles in the Z direction, but I only need the hair that's above the gray plane I can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

I need everything under that plane to be cut off.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear enough, basically I need everything under that plane to be cut off.

Comment: Are you planing on applying the particles?

Comment: Not really.....

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a plane
2. Add particles and select *Hair* (as you've already done)
3. Style you hair see the following GIF
   [image]
4. Now from *Modifiers* hit *Convert*

This will convert hair into a mesh

Now keep whatever you want, and delete whatever you don't need.

EDITED: To make it a little more controlled..

In these steps I gave thickness to "only-edges-mesh", because Hair by default are paths. converted into mesh by applying the modifier.

1. in this images.. I changed into "editable mode"
2. then selected "Edge" type (not vertex or face).
3. move to very close to the edge.
4. pressed "A" to select all edges (hair)
5. pressed "E" for extrude and pressed "x" to extruded the edge into "X" direction
6. pressed "A" again to select all edges
7. Pressed "E" to extrude and pressed "Y" to lock extrude only into "Y" direction.
   .. see these are no cubic hair.
8. Added a box to boolean hair with it. 
   [image: in these steps I gave thickness to "only-edges-mesh"]

in this image..I am modifying with "Boolean"

1. scaled up the newly added box
2. positioned the box
3. selected hair.. and applied "Boolean" Modifier.
4. changed the boolean type..
5. changed the view to wireframe so I could see .. what is going on.
6. scaled up the box to the desired form..
7. Apply this modifier and that's what you needed.. right?

[image]

Comment: Is there any way you can do it without free handing, using a curve or something?

Comment: these hairlines are already converted into mesh. But if you wouldn't have already given any thickness you can .. "press TAB" button, and under edit mode, select edges and "press E" extrude in any direction..  now you can use bool tool to subtract it. I'will make a gif for that too.. if you need?